# edit only part of a uitableview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am using the following code to edit a uitableview, but i'd like only one section to be editable - how should I do that? I cant seem to have access to "section" in the editing function below.

in viewDidLoad:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
```

Editing function:

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {

[super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
[tblSimpleTable setEditing:editing animated:YES];
if (editing) {
     editButton.enabled = NO;
} else {
    editButton.enabled = YES;
}
  }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The logic for that goes in `-tableView:canEditRowAtIndexPath:` of your table view controller (data source), like so:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Replace 0 with whichever section you want editable
    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        return YES;
    } else {
        return NO;
    }
}
```

If you're subclassing `UITableViewController`, you should be able to find this among the stub methods commented out beneath `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {
       if (indexPath.section == <your target section disable>) {
           return YES;
       }
       return NO;
 }
```

> you do not need to write the else part, canEditRowAtIndexPath return by default NO